# SQL Server triggers, recursive update

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, recursion, triggers

I have the table employees, which looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE employees
(
     id int primary key,
     name varchar(20) not null,
     boss int references employees(id),
     salary money,
);
```

Now I have to create a trigger, which after

```
UPDATE employees
SET money = 5000 
WHERE id = 1
```

change recursively managers' salary (difference between old and new salary amount to +500zł, employee from the UPDATE has 3 manages, so I want to update his salary and salaries of his managers, but every manager is a boss for his managers, so I want to update their salaries too.)

So ok, I've written the trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER salary_recursive ON employees
AFTER UPDATE
AS
  IF(SELECT salary FROM inserted)!=(SELECT salary FROM deleted)
  BEGIN
    declare @diff money = (SELECT salary FROM inserted) - (SELECT salary FROM deleted)
    update employees
    set salary = salary + @diff
    where boss = (SELECT id FROM inserted)
  END
```

It works correctly, but it updates only one level. So I've tried

```
ALTER DATABASE myDatabase
SET RECURSIVE_TRIGGERS ON
```

but it raises

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

How can I fix it?

Comment: You're treating the `inserted` table as if it had a single row, but that is not generally true.  Anyway, triggers are always a bad idea, this is as good a time as any to stop using them :)

Comment: It's my homework for Databases cours, so I can't make it in another way, I have to use triggers. BTW - what's the better idea for this task, than triggers? We haven't spoken about anything else than triggers yet.

Comment: @Andomar I disagree strongly with your statement that triggers are *always* a bad idea. They are not, you just have to be aware of a few things when working with triggers. But they can help you greatly if you know when and how to use them. Of course he could do the salary upgrade using a stored procedure and putting all the updates into that, too. That's what I'd do, but as he's in school learning about triggers...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in this line and other lines that are similar to

```
IF (SELECT salary FROM inserted) != (SELECT salary FROM deleted)
```

This will not work if the `SELECT` returns more than one value. You could try to rewrite this as follows:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM inserted i INNER JOIN deleted d ON d.id = i.id WHERE i.salary <> d.salary) BEGIN
    ...
END
```

The inner part of your block also has the same problem. You can actually solve this using a single SQL statement, but I can not test it right now. It might work along the lines of this:

```
UPDATE employees
SET
    salary = salary + (SELECT i.salary - d.salary FROM inserted i INNER JOIN deleted d ON d.id = i.id WHERE i.ID = employees.boss)
WHERE
    boss in (SELECT i.id FROM inserted i INNER JOIN deleted d ON d.id = i.id WHERE d.salary <> i.salary)
```

The idea is to update all the employees where the boss-id is one of the ids where the salary has changed. As there can be more than one record in `inserted`, you need to use `in` here.

The update adds to the salary field the difference between the new and old values where the salary id is the current record's boss-id.

Comment: Especially since the OP is still in school you would be better to not use the old style join syntax here. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Comment: You are right, esp. I'm mixing both, so I'm going to change that.